# Replace a url with another url from multiple files in a folder

Tags: linux

I want to replace the url from all files in a folder.
I am executing the following command. But getting "sed: 1: ".": invalid command code ."

find . -name '*' -exec sed -i 'shttp://test.thomas.com:81/https://jacob.com:88/g' {} \;

Can someone help in correcting this?

Comment: url "http://test.thomas.com" to be replaced with "https://jacob.com:88"

Comment: Please notice http and https and domain name differences

Comment: There is a `/` and escape sequences omitted, I guess. It should probably be `sed -i 's/http:\/\/test.thomas.com:81/https:\/\/jacob.com:88/g'`